# How do you ignore the 1st two lines of a CSV file in Dataweave?

Tags: csv, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 with Mule 3.8.1 and in the Transform Message component I have an input CSV file which has fieldnames on the 1st line and datatypes for that filed on the 2nd line.  I want to start processing the records from line 3 onwards, but cannot configure the Reader Configuration to miss the 2nd line containing the datatypes.

Is there a way I can do this so the 1st line is used for fieldnames, the 2nd line is ignored and the 3rd line onwards are the records that are processed?

**Test CSV:**

```
Product,Price
string,decimal(10,2)
phone,99
tv,499
```

**XML flow:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">
    <flow name="csvreaderFlow">
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="08c0a5d4-9d7d-44ad-b72b-bac83ab6b6c1" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="sample_data\list_csv.csv" mimeType="application/csv">
                <dw:reader-property name="bodyStartLineNumber" value="2"/>
            </dw:input-payload>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    products: payload01.Product
})]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Even if I increase the body line start number to 10, it still shows the 2 line and the 2 records to process.  I thought this would cause an error.

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Create a copy of the csv and remove the lines not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Input reader configuration for CSV on the Dataweave, they have a setting "bodyStartLineNumber" (set that to '3' in your case). Let me know if you have issues,

Here are the steps to be followed on the Dataweave,

```
1. Right click on the "Payload" label (left panel).
2. Click on the "Reader Configuration" option.
3. GUI opens with multiple options to be set.
4. Configure the "Body Start Line Number"
```

Comment: I have added the XML and test csv I am using.  I am looking to use the 1st line as the header, ignore the 2nd line and then phone and tv will be the records.  I have changed "Body Start Line Number" to 2 but I still get the 2nd line showing in Preview

Comment: Did u try setting it to 3??

Comment: I've tried it at 3 and even increased it to 10 which I thought I would have gotten an out of bound exception because there are only 3 records

Comment: Okay, let us try different strategy. Remove those settings related to body start line number. Instead use the below code...(payload filter $$ > 0) map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    products: payload01.Product
})

Comment: Thanks.  That got the result I was looking for.  Thanks for your help